# Using multiple layers from Tiled into Phaser game

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tiled

I'm creating a game with the Phaser engine, and I'm currently using the application 'Tiled' to create a my own tilemap.

The actual problem seems to be with having multiple layers when creating this tilemap. I have 6 different layers:

- "Background"
- "WallBlocks"
- "Grass"
- "SpikeAnimation"
- "DiamondAnimation"
- "SlimeAnimation"

Here is my Game.js file

```
SleepSim.Game = function (game) {
this.map;
this.Background;
this.WallBlocks;
this.Grass;
this.SpikeAnimation;
this.DiamondAnimation;
this.SlimeAnimation;
}
SleepSim.Game.prototype = {
create: function () {
    this.world.setBounds(0,0,5000,1000);

    this.map = this.add.tilemap('gameWorld');

    this.map.addTilesetImage('gameworld', 'tiles');

    this.Background = this.map.createLayer('Background');
    this.Background.resizeWorld();

    this.WallBlocks = this.map.createLayer('WallBlocks');
    this.Grass = this.map.createLayer('Grass');
    this.SpikeAnimation = this.map.createLayer('SpikeAnimation');
    this.DiamondAnimation = this.map.createLayer('DiamondAnimation');
    this.SlimeAnimation = this.map.createLayer('SlimeAnimation');
},
update: function() {
    if(this.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN)) {
        this.camera.y += 10;
    }
    else if (this.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP)){
        this.camera.y -= 10;
    }
    if (this.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT)){
        this.camera.x -= 10;
    }
    else if (this.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT)){
        this.camera.x += 10;
    }
}
}
```

I have the camera set this way at the moment to just fly through the map to make sure things can load.

Apologies if the formatting to this question is abit off, it's my first time posting! Any help would be super super appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. You only need to create a variable for the first layer, the rest should not be variables.

```
this.map = this.add.tilemap('gameWorld');

this.map.addTilesetImage('gameworld', 'tiles');

this.Background = this.map.createLayer('Background');
this.Background.resizeWorld();

this.map.createLayer('WallBlocks');
this.map.createLayer('Grass');
this.map.createLayer('SpikeAnimation');
this.map.createLayer('DiamondAnimation');
this.map.createLayer('SlimeAnimation');
```