# Phaser is not loading multiple layers of tilemap

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a Phaser Game.
And I am trying to load a Tilemap made in Tiled with 2 different layers.
The first layer loads correctly while the other layer does not load.
My code looks something like this:

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
    this.load.image("tiles", "assets/Tilesheet/tilesheet.png");
    this.load.image("background", "assets/Backgrounds/backgroundEmpty.png")
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON("world", "assets/Maps/map.json");
}

function create() {
    var map = this.make.tilemap({key: "world"});
    var tileset = map.addTilesetImage("tiles", "tiles");
    var background = map.addTilesetImage("background", "background");
    var Layer1 = map.createStaticLayer("Tile Layer 1", tileset, 0, 0);
    var Layer2 = map.createStaticLayer("Background Layer", background, 0, 0);
}
```

This is the result in console:
[image: The Console]

And this is the Tiled Layer:
[image: Tiled]

I cannot understand where am I going wrong.
Can someone point out the problem.

EDIT: Ok so I am pasting the JSON here:

```
{ "backgroundcolor":"#00cece",
 "compressionlevel":-1,
 "editorsettings":
    {
     "export":
        {
         "format":"json",
         "target":"map.json"
        }
    },
 "height":14,
 "infinite":false,
 "layers":[
        {
         "id":7,
         "image":"backgroundEmpty.png",
         "name":" Background Layer",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"imagelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }, 
        {
         "compression":"",
         "data":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHQAAAB0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAQAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAdAAAAHQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAEwAAABMAAAATAAAAEwAAABMAAAATAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAABMAAAATAAAAEwAAABMAAAATAAAAEwAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAEAAABMAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAATAAAAEwAAABMAAAATAAAAEwAAABMAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAEwAAABMAAAATAAAAEwAAABMAAAATAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAA=",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":14,
         "id":1,
         "name":"Tile Layer 1",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":25,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextlayerid":8,
 "nextobjectid":1,
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tiledversion":"1.4.2",
 "tileheight":64,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "columns":14,
         "firstgid":1,
         "image":"..\/Tilesheet\/tilesheet.png",
         "imageheight":448,
         "imagewidth":896,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"tiles",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":98,
         "tileheight":64,
         "tiles":[
                {
                 "id":0,
                 "objectgroup":
                    {
                     "draworder":"index",
                     "name":"",
                     "objects":[
                            {
                             "height":64,
                             "id":1,
                             "name":"",
                             "rotation":0,
                             "type":"",
                             "visible":true,
                             "width":64,
                             "x":0,
                             "y":0
                            }],
                     "opacity":1,
                     "type":"objectgroup",
                     "visible":true,
                     "x":0,
                     "y":0
                    }
                }, 
                {
                 "id":17,
                 "objectgroup":
                    {
                     "draworder":"index",
                     "name":"",
                     "objects":[
                            {
                             "height":64,
                             "id":1,
                             "name":"",
                             "rotation":0,
                             "type":"",
                             "visible":true,
                             "width":64,
                             "x":0,
                             "y":0
                            }],
                     "opacity":1,
                     "type":"objectgroup",
                     "visible":true,
                     "x":0,
                     "y":0
                    }
                }, 
                {
                 "id":42,
                 "objectgroup":
                    {
                     "draworder":"index",
                     "name":"",
                     "objects":[
                            {
                             "height":32,
                             "id":1,
                             "name":"",
                             "rotation":0,
                             "type":"",
                             "visible":true,
                             "width":64,
                             "x":0,
                             "y":0
                            }],
                     "opacity":1,
                     "type":"objectgroup",
                     "visible":true,
                     "x":0,
                     "y":0
                    }
                }],
         "tilewidth":64
        }],
 "tilewidth":64,
 "type":"map",
 "version":1.4,
 "width":25
}
```

Comment: Can you share the tilemap json? To verify your setup, it would help to see what the tilemap layers are named and how they're configured.

Comment: Thank You @brae for responding. I have edited the answer and included the JSON file.

Comment: Is this a single tilemap or are you trying to load a multiset tilemap?

Comment: The second layer is a Image Layer and I have imported the image. I also removed the variable `background` which makes the image a tile map and gave direct reference to the image like this: `var Level2 = map.createStaticLayer(" Background Layer", "background", 0, 0);`. But still nothing. @brae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra space in your tileset json for the Background Layer name. On this line: `"name":" Background Layer"`.

It's possible the whitespace is factored into the name it's expecting to create your layer. You can remove the whitespace and try that. Also, according to the [createStaticLayer Docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html#createStaticLayer__anchor), you can use the index of the layer OR the name. Try using the index to see if it's the whitespace making this layer invalid.

```
 var Layer2 = map.createStaticLayer(1, background, 0, 0);
```

There is also a currently unaccepted answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060119/using-multiple-layers-from-tiled-into-phaser-game?rq=1) that suggests you might not need the variable for the remaining layers once the initial layer is created. I'd recommend exploring that solution as well.

Comment: I tried `map.createStaticLayer(1, "background", 0, 0);`. The error changed to `Invalid Tilemap Layer ID: 1`. (I also tried removing the variable for the second layer as discussed in the other post)

Comment: According to your json the layer id of the ' Background Layer' is not `1` but `7`

Comment: Documentation and error messages hints about using layer Id (which is `7` in your json) but it seems to be index rather than Id, try `0` as index is zero-based.